# Loading animation for five different icons for uploading files

Tags: html

I have five `<svg>` tags that I should append the same animation to all of them, which their opacity is changing from 1 to 0 in an infinite loop. I want the animation to show the progress of uploading a file.
Any help would be appreciated.

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="4" height="4" viewBox="0 0 4 4">
        <g id="Group_1707" data-name="Group 1707" transform="translate(-331 -351)">
            <path id="Path_3284" data-name="Path 3284" d="M2,0A2,2,0,1,1,0,2,2,2,0,0,1,2,0Z"
                  transform="translate(331 351)" fill="#8c8c8c"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="4" height="4" viewBox="0 0 4 4">
        <g id="Group_1707" data-name="Group 1707" transform="translate(-339 -351)">
            <rect id="Rectangle_2599" data-name="Rectangle 2599" width="4" height="4" rx="2"
                  transform="translate(339 351)" fill="rgba(140,140,140,0.8)"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="4" height="4" viewBox="0 0 4 4">
        <g id="Group_1707" data-name="Group 1707" transform="translate(-347 -351)">
            <rect id="Rectangle_2600" data-name="Rectangle 2600" width="4" height="4" rx="2"
                  transform="translate(347 351)" fill="rgba(140,140,140,0.6)"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="4" height="4" viewBox="0 0 4 4">
        <g id="Group_1707" data-name="Group 1707" transform="translate(-355 -351)">
            <rect id="Rectangle_2601" data-name="Rectangle 2601" width="4" height="4" rx="2"
                  transform="translate(355 351)" fill="rgba(140,140,140,0.4)"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="4" height="4" viewBox="0 0 4 4">
        <g id="Group_1707" data-name="Group 1707" transform="translate(-363 -351)">
            <rect id="Rectangle_2602" data-name="Rectangle 2602" width="4" height="4" rx="2"
                  transform="translate(363 351)" fill="rgba(140,140,140,0.2)"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@keyframes` animation and `animation-delay`

```css
@keyframes loading{
  0%{
    opacity:1;
  }
  50%{
    opacity:0;
  }
}
svg{
  animation:loading 1s infinite;
}

svg:nth-of-type(1){
  animation-delay:0.2s;
}
svg:nth-of-type(2){
  animation-delay:0.4s;
}
svg:nth-of-type(3){
  animation-delay:0.6s;
}
svg:nth-of-type(4){
  animation-delay:0.8s;
}
svg:nth-of-type(5){
  animation-delay:1s;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="4" height="4" viewBox="0 0 4 4">
        <g id="Group_1707" data-name="Group 1707" transform="translate(-331 -351)">
            <path id="Path_3284" data-name="Path 3284" d="M2,0A2,2,0,1,1,0,2,2,2,0,0,1,2,0Z"
                  transform="translate(331 351)" fill="#8c8c8c"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="4" height="4" viewBox="0 0 4 4">
        <g id="Group_1707" data-name="Group 1707" transform="translate(-339 -351)">
            <rect id="Rectangle_2599" data-name="Rectangle 2599" width="4" height="4" rx="2"
                  transform="translate(339 351)" fill="rgba(140,140,140,0.8)"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="4" height="4" viewBox="0 0 4 4">
        <g id="Group_1707" data-name="Group 1707" transform="translate(-347 -351)">
            <rect id="Rectangle_2600" data-name="Rectangle 2600" width="4" height="4" rx="2"
                  transform="translate(347 351)" fill="rgba(140,140,140,0.6)"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="4" height="4" viewBox="0 0 4 4">
        <g id="Group_1707" data-name="Group 1707" transform="translate(-355 -351)">
            <rect id="Rectangle_2601" data-name="Rectangle 2601" width="4" height="4" rx="2"
                  transform="translate(355 351)" fill="rgba(140,140,140,0.4)"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
    <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="4" height="4" viewBox="0 0 4 4">
        <g id="Group_1707" data-name="Group 1707" transform="translate(-363 -351)">
            <rect id="Rectangle_2602" data-name="Rectangle 2602" width="4" height="4" rx="2"
                  transform="translate(363 351)" fill="rgba(140,140,140,0.2)"/>
        </g>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Smart, but just a note: the SVGs have some set transparencies in them, so the far right item will never reach full 1 opacity.